# Mutual Funds Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, classification, estimation, data-transformation

I am working on a dataset with aim to predict the MF ratings. There are cols like, 10 yr, 7 yr, 5 yr etc returns. I also have commencement date of MFs, the question is there are MFs with commencements dates only 3 yrs back, so would it be prudent to impute the returns for them for 10 yrs and 7 yrs period?

In my opinion that would be wrong, but then one of the requirements for ML models is to have no missing values in the data, and adding a 0 would be wrong too.

Need suggestions.